# What is this popup and can I use it in my own applications?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I was using Microsoft Edge (Chromium) today and saw an unusual popup saying "Sign in as" which I have not seen before. It had a username pre-filled and a "sign in" and "cancel" button. The popup appears as part of the browser chrome, similar to an alert() or prompt().

What feature is this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you had saved the password for your Twitter account in the MS Edge Chromium browser and **Sign in automatically** option is enabled.

[image]

So when you are trying to visit Twitter in private mode then the MS Edge Chromium browser is giving you the option to log in with that account without entering credentials.

This similar behavior is also available in the Google Chrome browser.

Reference:

[How can Instagram cause Chrome to attempt to login and show me my username when I'm using incognito mode?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/212882/how-can-instagram-cause-chrome-to-attempt-to-login-and-show-me-my-username-when)